# Which code-paths are causing CPU levels cache misses and how to avoid cache misses?

Tags: c++, caching, profiling, low-latency

I am using CentOS and my project is in c++ which is optimized but still the performance is not as expected. 
So i want to know which code-paths are causing CPU levels cache misses and how to avoid cache misses? If at all there is a tool available for this, then which tool to use and what is the command used to find misses?
I used perf tool however it just gives me the misses count but i want to know exactly where the miss happened.

Comment: You can probably try valgrind's `cachegrind`.

Comment: can you help me out with the command to find which part of the code caused cache miss using cachegrind

Comment: Check out `perf` - https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page